# blogger Invalid variable declaration in page skin

Tags: css, blogger

I have a problem with my blogger. Invalid variable declaration in page skin. The skin variables could not be parsed as they are not well-formed. Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SkinVariables>
    <Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#dd3333"/>
    <Group description="links color" selector="body">
        <Variable name="main.color" description="Main Theme Color" type="color" default="#dd3333"/>
    </Group> 
    <div><div>
</SkinVariables>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a value to the variables ?
try that , add values to all variables and change it as you need

```
<Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#dd3333" value="#dd3333"/>
```